# Variable assignment in an f-string

Tags: python-3.x, variables, variable-assignment, f-string

Question question regarding f-strings and expressions in Python 3.

The Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) states clearly that:

> Formatted string literals (also called f-strings for short) let you
> include the value of Python expressions inside a string by prefixing
> the string with f or F and writing expressions as {expression}.

A valid expression is: `{A = "A"}` but this doesn't work:

```
>>> print(f'{A = "A"} {A}')
    File "main.py", line 3
    print(f'{A = "A"} {A}')
          ^
SyntaxError: f-string: expecting '}'
```

What am I doing wrong here? My expression is valid. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding the documentation so if someone can clarify it would be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: "A valid expression is: `{A = "A"}` [...] My expression is valid." [assignment is not a valid python *expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Comment: @Masklinn You're correct. Thank you. I was frantically googling around and come across this: https://codepict.com/expressions-and-statements-in-python/

Which wrongfully states:

"So, the first combination x = 5 is an expression"

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes that helps, thank you.

Does the Python documentation have a list of what does and does not constitute an expression? Each language seems to define what is and isn't one differently and it's causing me a real headache.

Comment: @the_slug: Of course [it does](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)—it’s a bit technical, of course, since it’s a reference rather than a tutorial, but anything’s better than the nonsense you found!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do this:
print(f'A = {A}')